# user Powershell access (from admin perspective)

Tags: powershell, administrator

From an MS admin perspective what are some general dangers of users having access to powershell? Isn't it generally a good policy to disable cmd & powershell access for users? (in a typical corporate environment with typical security policies/software)

thanks

Comment: Having Powershell or command line access doesn't give the user any permissions they didn't already have. This question is probably better off on ServerFault.

Comment: No. Restricting applications is the wrong layer. Think UAC, filesystem, and group security. Also, think SuperUser or ServerFault; Stack Overflow is for programming.

Comment: Good luck blocking everything. Let's say you block cmd(remove the shortcut or something); then I would simply write a textfile with bat-extension or a vbscript to open a cmd or whatever I wanted. You would get lost in all the Software restrictions / Applocker policies. Dangerous actions usually requires admin-rights in the OS, so don't give it to your users. Also, harden your Windows environment with Group Policy. You could limit standard users alot using the old GP policies. This question is better suited for SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Actually, it'd probably be most on-topic on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/). However, regardless of whether you put this question on SuperUser, ServerFault, InfoSec or any other site, I consider it to be far too broad to be answerable in a reasonable way.

Comment: @Phylogenesis is correct. The user's account is the security boundary, not powershell.exe or cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it generally a good policy to disable cmd & powershell access for users?

No, because the user's account is the security boundary, not the programs a user runs. A program is not a security boundary because it runs under the context of the user that starts it. Just because a user runs cmd.exe or powershell.exe does not somehow grant them extra magical powers to bypass security.

Comment: That article refers to system services. In that case you're already on the other side of the airtight hatchway.

Comment: Just wanted to point out (for the sake of completeness) that there are situations where user contexts aren't as clearly separated from each other as one would like to think.

Comment: The same principle applies whether the program is running as a system service or not. The account that's running the program is the security boundary, not the program that's running. In the case of a system service, as I said, [you're already on the other side of the airtight hatchway](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/02/10057047.aspx).

Comment: That is not what I'm talking about. [This is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack).

Comment: The shatter attack is pretty old (13 years at this point) and, [as noted](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc750553.aspx), could only potentially be exploited in a badly designed service in old OSes that are no longer supported (see [Larry Osterman's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/09/14/466175.aspx)). This old vulnerability still does not violate the basic principle already adduced.

Comment: Yes. But it illustrates that user boundaries *might* be crossed under certain circumstances. That's all I meant to point out. Nota bene: you wouldn't believe just how many interactive services are still out there (not to mention "administrators" using `instsrv.exe` et al. to install GUI applications as services). :(

Comment: A badly designed system service (or an administrator running a service in an ill-advised way) still presumes you are starting out on the other side of the airtight hatchway. A standard user cannot install a system service or bypass security by running an executable.

Comment: Nobody claimed otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your caveat. It sounds like we agree.